# mysql join select explained

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables: 'posts' and 'users' every post has a 'ref_id' column to get the user id who posted it.

Now, I am getting posts this way:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE time > '$timeLimit' LIMIT 50");
```

I can't understand how to join every result to get the poster related data as well. What I am doing right now is basically a loop inside a loop, where foreach of the result, get their user info. But it is pretty obvious that this is very wrong,

Apparently I need to start using joins, but how does one do it? this should be a really simple example to work with, I suppose.

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT posts.*, users.* 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users 
  ON posts.posted_by = users.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT
  posts.*,,
  users.Username
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON posts.ref_id = users.user_id;
```

---

### Explanation:

To `JOIN` to any tables with each others, there are two things; the `JOIN` type and the join condition. There are three main types of join:

- `INNER JOIN`, only the rows that match the join condition will be returned from the two tables no more rows. But:
- `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, when you join two tables you will have one on the left of the join keyword and the other one will be in the right:

  FROM Table1                   <------------- This is the left table.
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ....   <------------- This is the right table.

In `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the unmatched rows from the left table will be included in the result set.

- `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` the unmatched rows from the right table will be included in the result set.
- `CROSS JOIN` this will perform a Cartesian product from the two tables.

In our query, the query will reutrn all the users from the `users` table only if the `ref_id` equal to the `user_id` column form the `posts` table.

For more information and explanations:

- [**A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).
- [**Another Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).
- [**Join syntax in MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user.name
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts
ON posts.ref_id == user.id
AND posts.time > 50
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: why are you selecting from users?